# Separability of Minkowski Sum of well-behaved sets

Tags: gn.general-topology, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $A$ and $C$ be non-empty simply connected and connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and suppose that $C$ is convex.  Then is the Minkowski sum $A+C$ separable?

Comment: What do you mean by "separable" ?

Comment: There's a dense separable subspace, since both $A$  and $C$ are subspace of a Euclidean space

Comment: Then it's true, because any subset of a separable metric space is also separable.

Comment: Maybe @FlabbyTheKatsu had in mind that $A+C$ is simply connected? In this case the answer is negative: take for $A$ the letter $C$ and for $B$ the letter $I$ on the plane.

Comment: Yes, I meant to ask as Taras said.  Thank you for the anwser.